# 表領域の作成でエラー

Tags: sql, oracle

TBS_USER_IDXの表領域の作成

```
create tablespace TBS_USER_IDX                  
datafile 'C:\app\oracle\oradata\orcl\TBS_USER_IDX.dbf' size 128m                    
autoextend on next 16m maxsize 1024m;
```

エラーは

```
ORA-01119: データベース・ファイル'C:\app\oracle\oradata\orcl\TBS_USER_IDX.dbf'の作成中にエラーが発生しました。
ORA-27040: ファイルの作成エラー、ファイルを作成できません
error in creating database file '%s'"
*Cause:    Usually due to not having enough space on the device.
```

どのように対処すればいいでしょうか。

Comment: 次の２点を確認してはいかがでしょうか。1)`Cドライブ‘に十分な空き領域はあるか？　2)'C:\app\oracle\oradata\orcl'は存在しているか？　2)の存在が必須かどうかはわかりませんが、もし存在していない場合はフォルダを作成してから、もう一度試してみるのもいいと思います。

Comment: Cドライブには122GBの空き容量があります。
C:\app\oracle\oradata\orcl'のフォルダも作成しました。

Comment: それでもうまくいきませんでした。エラーは同じです。

Comment: `create tablespace`を実行したユーザについて 'C:\app\oracle\oradata\orcl'の各フォルダのプロパティ、セキュリティタブを調べて適切な権限が付与されているかを確認してはいかがでしょうか。

Comment: それでうまくいきました。ありがとうございます。

Comment: 具体的に何が原因だったのか、自己回答をあげて欲しいです。いつか同じ問題に悩むひとが出てくるかもしれません。

Comment: １．コントロールパネルを開く。
２．管理ツールを開く。
３．サービスを開く。
４．SQL Server（インスタンス名）のプロパティを開く。
５．「ログオン」タブをクリック。
６．ログオンを「ローカルシステムアカウント」に変更し、「デスクトップとの対話をサービスに許可」をチェック、「OK」をクリック。
７．SQL Server（インスタンス名）を右クリックして再起動。
これで解決しました。

Comment: スタック・オーバーフローでは [自己回答](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) も歓迎しています。コメント欄はあくまでメモ書きという位置付けなので、「回答」の形で投稿してもらうと同じような問題で困ったユーザーがいた際に情報が見つけやすくなります。

Answer (score 1):

以下の手順で解決しました。

1. コントロールパネルを開く。
2. 管理ツールを開く。
3. サービスを開く。
4. SQL Server（インスタンス名）のプロパティを開く。
5. 「ログオン」タブをクリック。
6. ログオンを「ローカルシステムアカウント」に変更し、「デスクトップとの対話をサービスに許可」をチェック、「OK」をクリック。
7. SQL Server（インスタンス名）を右クリックして再起動。

---

*この投稿は [@user25636 さんのコメント](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/62474/%e8%a1%a8%e9%a0%98%e5%9f%9f%e3%81%ae%e4%bd%9c%e6%88%90%e3%81%a7%e3%82%a8%e3%83%a9%e3%83%bc#comment68365_62474) の内容を元に コミュニティwiki として投稿しました。*

Answer (score 0):

## 回答

エラーメッセージは「十分な空き領域はあるか」と読めますが、原因の一例をあげているだけです。ファイルが作成できない原因は他にも考えられるため、以下を確認してください。

- 十分な空き領域はあるか？

  - 空き領域がない場合は、空き領域を増やすか、空きのあるファイルシステムに作成場所を変更する。
- 物理ファイルを配置するディレクトリが存在しているか？

  - ディレクトリが存在しない場合は作成する。
- 物理ファイルを配置するディレクトリ(祖先のディレクトリも)に対して、処理を実行するユーザがアクセスできる権限が付与されているか？

  - 実行するユーザに権限を付与する。
  - 権限が付与されたユーザで実行する。